# grouping python dictionaries by keys from a dictionary of items

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new to python and I;m tring to group the existing python dictionary by key. 
I have a dictionary like this.

```
a = {'a1':'obj_1','b1':'obj_2','c1':'obj_3','a2':'obj_4','b2':'obj_5','c2':'obj_6'}
```

i want to create another dictionary by grouping all items togeather starting with 'a','b','c' as below:

```
{'aonly': {'a1': 'obj_1','a2': 'obj_4'}, 'bonly': {'b1': 'obj_2','b2': 'obj_5'}, 'conly': {'c1': 'obj_3','c2': 'obj_6'}}
```

The solution that I tried was :

```
    d = {}
    for k,v in a.items():
    print(k)
    print(v)
    if 'a' in k:
        d.setdefault('a',{k:v})
    elif 'b' in k:
        d.setdefault('b',{k:v})
    elif 'c' in k:
        d.setdefault('c',{k:v})
print(d)
```

but this does not give the proper output.

Other solution that i tried was

```
l= []
m = []
n = []

d = {}
for i in a:

    if 'a' in i:
        l.append({i:a[i]})
        d['aonly'] = l
    elif 'b' in i:
        m.append({i:a[i]})
        d['bonly'] = m
    elif 'c' in i:
        n.append({i:a[i]})
        d['conly']  = n
print(d)
```

This kind of serves my purpose but that not effective because of the use of list etc. is there a better way to solve this?

also, in the second piece of the code,
why is the assignment on a single line give bizzare result?

```
l = m = n = []
```

please advise.

I kind of read through the defaultDict from collections mode but got little confused with my requirement. can someone help me with this pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for i in {k[0] for k in a}:
    d_dict[i + 'only'] = {k:v for k,v in a.items() if k[0]==i}

print (dict(d_dict))
#{'conly': {'c1': 'obj_3', 'c2': 'obj_6'}, 'aonly': {'a1': 'obj_1', 'a2': 'obj_4'}, 'bonly': {'b1': 'obj_2', 'b2': 'obj_5'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, i tried this and this serves the purpose to. But i like the solution using defaultdict and that executes pretty fast as well.

```
d = {}
for k,v in a.items():
    if 'a' in k:
        d.setdefault('a',{})
        d['a'][k] = v
    elif 'b' in k:
        d.setdefault('b',{})
        d['b'][k] = v
    elif 'c' in k:
        d.setdefault('c',{})
        d['c'][k] = v
print(d)
```